# ASP.NET passing values between redirect & postback

Tags: asp.net

First of all, thanks for reading.

I will describe my situation as explicitly as I can.

I have a page where users can leave comments.
Here's the commenting flow

- A-1. 'comment' button is clicked
- A-2. a modal popup with a textbox is shown using ModalPopupExtender in ajaxtoolkit.
- A-3. User types a comment in the textbox, and click "ok".

However, when user is not logged in, expected behavior changes.

- B-1. 'comment' button is clicked
- B-2. a Login modal-popup with id & pwd textbox is shown.
- B-3. User types ID & pwd, and click ok.
- B-4. Comment-modal-popup is shown
- B-5. user types a comment and click ok.

**I have a PROBLEM handing this case.**

When B-3 occurs, page is posted back, i log the user in, update session object, and I Response.Rediect() the page to itself to display correct logged-in status (i have to..).
After redirect, in Page_Load(), I need to check some values to show Comment-Modal-Popup.
But I'm not sure how..

Here's what i considered

- ViewState

  - i just can't use it since the page was redirected not posted back.
- QueryString

  - I could have add "showCommentPopup=1" on URL when redirecting, but that will leave unwanted QueryString in URL. I don't want users to misuse it.
- Session

  - I actually used Session object. Before redirection, I set Session[ "ShowCommentPopup" ] to true. In Page_Load() if it is set, i remove it and show the popup.

using Session like i did doesn't work correctly when user opens same page in multiple tabs.

1. user opens two tabs(in Firefox) with same URL
2. user follows steps from B-1 to B-3 in first tab.
3. before the page is redirected between B-3 and B-4, user refreshes second tab.
4. if the timing is right, comment-popup is shown in the second tab.

I expect to hear great insights from stackoverflow..

Comment: Why do you *have* to redirect to handle the login? Normally, you should be able to do so without redirecting if you've already prompted for their name and password.

Comment: You are right, I can handle login without redirect. It is displaying correct logged-in status I can't do.. the page uses black-box control to display login status, and it only shows correct logged-in status after page is redirected.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this but I think if you store your `ShowCommentPopup` flag in the `HttpContext.Items` collection instead of the session and then use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect` you should be able to achieve the desired results.

**`HttpContext.Items`** is a dictionary that can be used to store data whose lifetime is the lifetime of the request.  This means a second request from a different tab or window will have a different `HttpContext.Items` dictionary.

**`Server.Transfer`** is somewhat like `Response.Redirect` in that it allows you to load a "different" URL instead of the original.  However, while `Reponse.Redirect` initiates a new request, `Server.Transfer` transfers the existing request to the new page on the server.

A better explanation of the differences between `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer` can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641).

**Example**

---

```
bool showCommentPopup = false;
if (HttpContext.Current.Items["ShowCommentPopup"] != null)
{
    showCommentPopup  = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Items["ShowCommentPopup"];
}

//...

HttpContext.Current.Items["ShowCommentPopup"] = true;
```

Comment: woo~ i never knew about HttpContext.Items. I tried it and i could get the flag correctly. However login process was effectively canceled after Server.Transfer. In the event handler, i did, Login using Forms -> Set the flag -> Server.Transfer(). So I set additional flags for login info, and it worked!!! Thanks very much!!! I learned a lot

Answer (score 0):

You've clearly thought your solutions through!  I'm guessing the problem with the Session was that they could comment on a different page than the one they logged into.  You could get around this by storing the session var, not as a bool, but as the page to show it on:

```
var uniqueString = this.ToString() + uniquePageID;
if (Session["ShowCommentPage"].ToString() == uniqueString)
  //show modal & remove session var
```

Now your program only "breaks" when the user visits the same object in two different windows, logs in on Window #1, and refreshes on Window #2.  And it's not really breaking since they wind up commenting on the same object either way.

The reason I used uniquePageID, is cause I'm figuring you have a template page ("showObject.aspx") with arguments on which to show ("showObject.aspx?objectID=3").  In order to make sure the comment is left on the same ID, it needs to be present in `uniqueString`

Comment: Yes this method works and user won't be leaving comments on wrong page. Still the popup could be shown in Window #2 not in Window #1 which triggered whole events. I think this is a problem in User Experience. Optimally, I wish i could solve that too.

Comment: thanks very much for taking your time and answer my question :)